# Nifi Jolt transform JSON into array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have Json files coming from Kafka, that I need to insert into a Hive table, using Apache Nifi. The Jsons have multiple nested fields, or arrays of nested fields.
The schema of the Hive table is defined in such a way that we can insert (and then query) these nested fields and nested arrays.

My problem is that some fields are arrays in some messages, while they are simple Json structures in other messages :

Case 1:

```json
{
  "some_field": {
    "nested_field": {
      "tag1": "value",
      "tag2": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Case 2:

```json
{
  "some_field": {
    "nested_field": [
      {
        "tag1": "value",
        "tag2": "..."
      },
      {
        "tag1": "value",
        "tag2": "..."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The Hive table schema can only work for one of those cases, but not both.

Seeing as there is a majority of messages like case 2, I was thinking of using Jolt to transform case 1 into case 2 with only one element in the array. That I can do easily with Jolt :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "some_field": {
        "nested_field": {
          "*": "some_field.nested_field[0].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But then it messes up with messages that are already in the array form.

Is there some way to have a generic transformation that deals with case 1 without messing with case 2?

Or alternatively, is there a way to filter out flowfiles that do not match the given schema? (I know I can use Jolt to filter out fields that do not match the schema, but that's not ideal)

Answer (score 0):

You rather can use a **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation spec which contains a **`toList`** function such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // "*" represents "some_field"
        "*": "=toList" // "*" represents "nested_field"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which converts innermost object into an array for the **case1** while it doesn't apply any change on the **case2**.